# Azure Data Factory - Capture error details of a dataflow activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a data flow and my requirement is to capture the error details into a variable when it fails and assign this variable to a parameter in the next data flow. I tried to achieve this until the second stage(With help) as below, but I'm unable to get this variable assigned to a parameter in the next data flow. The error I get is - Expression cannot be parsed

[image: Pipeline Flow]

[image: First Dataflow Error]

[image: Variable output]

[image: Dataflow 2 parameters]

[image: Failure message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the dataflow error message, connect the dataflow activity upon failure to the set variable activity to store the error message using the expression:

```
@string(json(activity('Data flow1').error.message).Message)
```

[image]

> **Error Message:**

[image: Ref2]

> **Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Vamsi, Thanks a lot! This works. When I'm trying to assign this variable to a parameter in the next dataflow, it is failing - 'Job failed due to reason: Expression cannot be parsed'. Any suggestion here, please?

Comment: Hey @VivekKB, you can edit the question to provide images and details of this error so the issue can be resolved

Comment: Hi @Vamsi, I have posted a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73416911/azure-data-factory-capture-error-details-of-a-dataflow-activity-store-into