# Azure Data Factory - Capture error details of a dataflow activity -> Store into a variable -> Assign this variable to a dataflow parameter

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a data flow and my requirement is to capture the error details into a variable when it fails and assign this variable to a parameter in the next data flow. I tried to achieve this until the second stage(With help) as below, but I'm unable to get this variable assigned to a parameter in the next data flow. The error I get is - Expression cannot be parsed

What do I do later?
This parameter is assigned to a column in the data flow and I use this column to update the table in the dedicated pool with the relevant error message.

[image: Pipeline Flow]

[image: First Dataflow Error]

[image: Variable output]

[image: Dataflow 2 parameters]

[image: Failure message]

[image: Dataflow]

[image: Dataflow 1]

Comment: Hi @Vivek KB, can you please add details about how you are using the parameters passed from `geterrormessagetostoreindedicatedpooltable` to respective dataflow

Comment: Hi Vamsi, I have updated my query to include more details. Looking forward to your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and I got the same error**

The above scenario fails,  because dataflow fails to parse `' '` and  `/` in your error message.

**To resolve above error,please follow below steps:**

- I just create the error `fail1` with  message containing a different character.

[image: ref1]

- Go to set variable : Create a variable and added dynamic content to the value.

`@replace(replace(string(activity('Fail1').output.message),pipeline().parameters.quote,'"'),'\','/')`

[image: Ref1]

**Output:**

[image: Ref2]

**Updated:**

> **Parameter**

[image: Ref]

Comment: What is -> pipeline().parameters.quote in your expression?

Comment: Hi @VivekKB, the value of my quote parameter is `'` (one single quote).